# Neo4j Console doesn't run Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to use Cypher in neo4j to create nodes, but whenever I type cypher commands in the "neo4j shell" of the "Power Tool Console", I end up with the following error:

```
Unknown command 'create(n);'
```

I have no "Cypher" tab in my console, unlike what the Neo4j Documentation claims I should have (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/webadmin-console.html). I only have the "Neo4j Shell","Gremlin", and "HTTP" tabs.

How can I input Cypher commands in the "Neo4j Shell" tab? 
Is there any way I can actually retrieve a "Cypher" tab? Sorry if these are very easy questions, but I am totally new to neo4j, and I found nothing like this on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter commands in the neo4j tab of the "powertool console" as well as in the "data browser". Try for example `START n = node(*) return n;`. The problem with `create(n)` is that the console seems to view it as one command. `create (n)` (notice the blank) does work.

Comment: So just to check, should I be typing something like this:
`neo4j-sh (?)$ create(n)`

Comment: with a space between `create` and `(n)`

Comment: Hmmm...when I try to do that, I get no error message, but the node isn't created. When I assign a property to `n` and try to return `n`, I get nothing. I tried this: `CREATE (a { name : 'Andres' }) RETURN a`

Answer (score 0):

You may have installed a different version than what the documentation is describing.

I installed `neo4j 1.9` with `brew` and see the same tabs you see.

Then I uninstalled it and downloaded the latest neo4j to try again, this time I have somewhere to input Cypher.